# AWS - Elastic Beanstalk Sidekiq Not Starting Automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, sidekiq, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hey I'm running a rails application on an `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` instance and have run into a couple issues using Sidekiq for background jobs.  I'm using Sidekiq to send welcome and password reset emails.

The application is running `Rails 4.2.3`.  The Elastic Beanstalk instance is running `64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.1 running Ruby 2.2 (Puma)`.  I used the following [tutorial](https://medium.com/@benhansen/setting-up-sidekiq-redis-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-with-elasticache-2efeb32935fe#.bwfl65dnl) to set up a `Redis` node and `Sidekiq` on Elastic Beanstalk, and used the `sidekiq.config` from the following [GIST](https://gist.github.com/gcarrion-gfrmedia/11396682#file-0003_sidekiq-config) to place inside my `.ebextentions` folder.  I did not use any of the other recommended config files from the GIST.

Everything seemed to go off without a hitch.  The application deployed correctly and there were no errors in any of the logs.  However, when I created a new user, triggering a welcome email, the email failed to send.  I checked the `Sidekiq` web application and it appeared that my jobs were scheduled but never executed.  On further inspection I determined that `Sidekiq` wasn't actually running.  I connected to the EC2 instance via SSH and manually ran `bundle exec sidekiq` and the email sent.

For some reason `Sidekiq` isn't getting run when the application is being deployed.

Here are the contents of my `sidekiq.config`:

```
# Sidekiq interaction and startup script
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/50_restart_sidekiq":
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash

      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/envvars

      PIDFILE=$EB_CONFIG_APP_PIDS/sidekiq.pid

      cd $EB_CONFIG_APP_CURRENT

      if [ -f $PIDFILE ]
      then
        SIDEKIQ_LIVES=$(/bin/ps -o pid= -p `cat $PIDFILE`)
          if [ -z $SIDEKIQ_LIVES ]
          then
             rm -rf $PIDFILE
          else
             kill -TERM `cat $PIDFILE`
             sleep 10
             rm -rf $PIDFILE
          fi
      fi

      BUNDLE=/usr/local/bin/bundle
      SIDEKIQ=/usr/local/bin/sidekiq

      $BUNDLE exec $SIDEKIQ \
        -e production \
        -P /var/app/containerfiles/pids/sidekiq.pid \
        -C /var/app/current/config/sidekiq.yml \
        -L /var/app/containerfiles/logs/sidekiq.log \
        -d

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03_mute_sidekiq":
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash

      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/envvars

      PIDFILE=$EB_CONFIG_APP_PIDS/sidekiq.pid

      if [ -f $PIDFILE ]
      then
        SIDEKIQ_LIVES=$(/bin/ps -o pid= -p `cat $PIDFILE`)
          if [ -z $SIDEKIQ_LIVES ]
          then
             rm -rf $PIDFILE
          else
             kill -USR1 `cat $PIDFILE`
             sleep 10
          fi
      fi
```

What am I missing?  Are there other files I need to add to my `.ebextentions` folder?  Why isn't `Sidekiq` being initiated?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Did you find the answer?